# insertar valores a una variable tipo tabla en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo 1 variable tipo tabla.

```
DECLARE @TblAreasNoBloqueadas TABLE 
        (
            Id int identity,
            Fecha VARCHAR(10),
            Observacion VARCHAR(max)
        )
```

y tengo otras variables que almacenan unos valores.

```
DECLARE @Dia varchar(10)
DECLARE @Observacion varchar(max)

set @Dia = '20190728'
set @Observacion = 'No se pudo bloquear esta area'
```

la pregunta es ¿como puedo insertar los valores de esas variables en la variable tipo tabla?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Una tabla tipo variable no deja de ser un tabla como cualquier otra, por lo que la clásica clausula de `insert` funciona:

```
INSERT INTO @TblAreasNoBloqueadas (Fecha, Observacion) VALUES (@Dia, @Observacion)
```

O bien,

```
INSERT INTO @TblAreasNoBloqueadas (Fecha, Observacion) 
SELECT @Dia, 
       @Observacion
```